# Couchbase Gem on Mac Yosemite

Tags: ruby, rubygems, couchbase, osx-yosemite

I have installed libcouchbase using homebrew and also building from source following these instructions http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-c-2.4/ but still get the error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing couchbase:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for lcb_iops_wire_bsd_impl2(NULL, 0) in -lcouchbase... no

**********************************************************************
* You must install libcouchbase >= 2.4.0
* See http://www.couchbase.com/communities/c/ for more details
**********************************************************************

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I'm using ruby 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message, it would appear you need the latest version of libcouchbase. Ensure you do a `brew update` first so that brew is aware of the latest version.

```
mnunberg@mbp15 ~ $ cbc version
cbc:
  Runtime: Version=2.4.6, Changeset=803c3c79cd72455aa62ab39eaf7a597e5d6de7e5
  Headers: Version=2.4.6, Changeset=803c3c79cd72455aa62ab39eaf7a597e5d6de7e5
  IO: Default=libevent, Current=libevent
  SSL: .. SUPPORTED
```